# Интеграция SQLite в системе и Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, entity-framework

Есть SQLite. Есть для него EF. Теперь осталось интегрировать SQLite в систему, чтобы не использовать всякие сторонние приблуды, а пользоваться VS dev only.

Я установил какую то хрень от деварта, которая называется dotConnect for SQLite вот отсюда http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/download.html 
и, о чудо, в Server Explorer появилась возможность подключаться к базе SQLite. Правда новый файл она не создает (хотя такая возможность вроде бы предусматривалась). И таблицы создать нельзя в новом файле (который я просто создал в проводнике). Но что самое печальное, нет возможности подключиться к базе SQLite средствами EF при создании Model-first или Base-first. Там вообще дают на выбор SQL server и локальный SQL Server (хотя в Server Explorer выбор побогаче). Кстати, почему EDM не тянет подключение из App.config?

Почему так криво все? Вроде SQLite распространенная база и используется в мелкософте даже.

Comment: Может я не прав, но зачем еще что-то городить поверх простой и лаконичной SQLite, я не знаю. Мне хватает nuget пакета `sqlite-net-pcl` и расширения `SQLite Manager` для Firefox.

Comment: @Bulson, да мне всего хватает, кроме централизованности. Хочу все делать в одном IDE